# XPath selecting explicit element comparing on value

Tags: html, xpath, siblings

This is what I have tried so far..

```
//div[@id='information']//div[div=='Site']
//div[text()='Site']//span//a[@href]
```

I am fiddling with an XPath expression but it´s not working out. I want to select the anchor's href attribute. Thats no problem but it needs to be explicitly **after** a `div` with `class` `h3` AND a `value = "Site"`.

```
<div id="information">
    <div class="h3">Location</div>
    <div class="h3">Site</div>
    <span>
        //Here is sometimes a <br/>
        <a href='http://www.test.at'>Klick</a>
    </span>
    <div class="h3">Referenz</div>
    <span>12345</span>
</div>
```

There can be arbitrarily many div elements inside the div with id="information" so selecting on index is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
//div[@class = 'h3'][. = 'Site']/following-sibling::*/descendant-or-self::a/@href
```

This will extract the `href` attributes of all `a` tags that are after the "Site" div in document order but still contained within the same parent element (the "information" div in your example).  If you're not bothered about that last bit, i.e. you want to include `a` tags that occur *after* the "information" div as well as inside it, then you can use the simpler

```
//div[@class = 'h3'][. = 'Site']/following::a/@href
```